# Fast parallel multiplication method

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, optimization, binary

In page 6 of [A very fast multiplication algorithm](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/0167-9260(83)90005-6) , how do the PAR-allel multiplication work ?

Why is 12021011 equivalent to 299 ?

[Parallel Multiplication method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpF0q.png)

Answer (score 0):

12021011 is $100101011_2 = 299_{10}$ *before* the carry.

The rough idea of algorithm:

(1) divide the factors in chunks,

(2) do in parallel the product of chunks,

[now, we must shift and add the (many) chunks]

(3) do in parallel the shifts,

(4) take the (say) S shifted chunks in subsets of 2 and do in parallel the S/2 sums,

(5) repeat the procedure with the S/2 sums

...

Comment: Why is 12021011 equivalent to 100101011 in binary ?

Comment: Ok, I got it now. But why is this parallel multiplication method faster than [carry save array multiplier](https://i.imgur.com/oNmRaRa.png) ? Note that those '2' also needs additions by itself ....

Comment: @kevin it is hardware implementation. You should look at Wallace tree, carry save adder, carry skip adder to understand better.

Comment: @kelalaka Wallace tree is no longer used now due to its irregular and famously long routing.